# Language switcher

Tags: switch, language

Using this plug-in.
http://biberltd.com/en/documentation/software/biber_ltd_multi_language_support/

How can I switch from one language to another.

I've got the code switching from FR/EN on the top right menu but can't get it to work when a user is deaper into the site.

I'm confused between settings in my htaccess and site structure could anyone offer any insight?

Language switching works from main site: link to site in question: http://kanuk.com/dev/

Language switching does not work from deeper link: http://kanuk.com/dev/index.php/Collection/femmes/manteaux-chauds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of your index.php isn't included in your language changer link.

http://kanuk.com/dev/index.php/Collection/femmes/manteaux-chauds

goes to:

http://kanuk.com/dev/fr/Collection/femmes/manteaux-chauds

which is missing the index.php element:

http://kanuk.com/dev/fr/**index.php**/Collection/femmes/manteaux-chauds/

Either modify your htaccess so it [removes the index.php](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html) (recommended), or change the links in the language changer so they generate the URL with index.php in it.